# Single and Double quote issues in print php variables

Tags: php

Am echoing php variables which works fine but when i tried to output image, nothing seems to work
working.php

```
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b>$address<br><br>$desc');\n");
```

not_working.php
for image display, i added

```
<img src='http://localhost/services/status/" .$pic. "'>
```

hence

```
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,<img src='http://localhost/services/status/" .$pic. "'>,'<b>$name</b>$pic<br><br>$desc');\n");
```

Any Help

Answer (score 2):

The [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) about strings should clarify your issue, i hope. In simple words, variables are not expanded (parsed) in single quotes.

Best solution is to use sprintf:

```
sprintf('<img src="http://localhost/services/status/%s">', $pic);
```

OK solution:

```
echo '<img src="http://localhost/services/status/' . $pic . '">'
```

Not so ok solution:

```
echo "<img src=\"http://localhost/services/status/$pic\">"
```

Comment: And in addition, in your `<img...` sample, you are mixing single und double quotes.

Comment: Also, `echo` is not a function but a language construct and does not need parenthesis.